# Why is my user's X-CSRF-Token header different form the _csrf_token in the session?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, csrf

For a very small number of users (who are making legitimate requests) on my site, the X-CSRF-Token header sent with their AJAX requests is different from the _csrf_token in their (cookie store) session (and the rest of their session seems normal). Consequently, they are getting buggy behavior and errors. Any insight into how this could happen?

Using Rails 2.3.11 on REE 1.8.7 on Heroku & jQuery 1.4.2.

Comment: Is this problem related to any particular browser or not?

Comment: It's not. A brief glance through the logs shows it happening on all versions of IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

Comment: This might help.. since it is related to Rails(Rails 3 particularly) in a way:-http://www.jigsawboys.com/2011/05/19/valum-fileupload-jquery-csrf/.. just give it a look..

Comment: Like I said, I'm sending the X-CSRF-Token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem disappeared after upgrading to Rails 3